# Why is the name of the files affecting the structs in C++?

Tags: c++, extern

Using the below code:

```
//h.cpp
#include "main.h"
#include "api/core.hpp"
extern pros::Motor frontLeft;
extern pros::Motor rearLeft;
extern pros::Motor frontRight;
extern pros::Motor rearRight;
extern pros::Motor leftLift;
extern pros::Motor rightLift;
extern pros::Motor leftRoller;
extern pros::Motor rightRoller;
Motor_Group fullDrive({frontLeft,rearLeft,frontRight,rearRight});
Motor_Group leftDrive({frontLeft,rearLeft});
Motor_Group rightDrive({frontRight,rearRight});
Motor_Group lift({leftLift,rightLift});
Motor_Group roller({leftRoller,rightRoller});
Motor_Group test({frontLeft,rearLeft});
```

```
//config.h
#include "api/core.hpp"


extern Motor_Group test;
extern Motor_Group fullDrive;
extern Motor_Group leftDrive;
extern Motor_Group rightDrive;
extern Motor_Group lift;
extern Motor_Group roller;
```

```
//initialize.cpp
#include "main.h"
#include "config.h"
pros::Motor frontLeft(1);
pros::Motor rearLeft(2);
pros::Motor frontRight(3);
pros::Motor rearRight(4);
pros::Motor leftLift(1);
pros::Motor rightLift(1);
pros::Motor leftRoller(1);
pros::Motor rightRoller(1);
void initialize(){
  pros::lcd::initialize();
  test.move(127);
}
```

the `.move()` function does not work as expected. The motors does not move a bit. I believe that the `extern test` creates an empty class. I think this is because of the alphabetical order the compiler compiles things. If I rename h.cpp to j.cpp(which is alphabetically after initialize), it works perfectly fine. Is there a way to work around this or do the h.cpp file should be alphabetically after all other cpp files? I tried changing the name of the config.h file but it doesn't matter.
Edit:For you info, here is core.h and core.cpp

```
//core.h
#ifndef _CORE_HPP_
#define _CORE_HPP_
#include "main.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>

void wait(int ms);
struct Motor_Group{
  std::vector<pros::Motor> motor_vector;

  int speed = 0;

  Motor_Group(std::initializer_list<pros::Motor> port_set);

  pros::Motor get(short idx);

  short size();

  void move(short speed);

  float position();

  void tare();
};
/*...*/
```

```
//core.cpp
#include "globals.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "core.hpp"
#include <functional>
#include <map>
void wait(int ms){
  pros::delay(ms);
}
Motor_Group::Motor_Group(std::initializer_list<pros::Motor> port_set)
{
  this->motor_vector = std::vector(port_set);
}
pros::Motor Motor_Group::get(short idx)
{
  return this->motor_vector[idx];
}
short Motor_Group::size()
{
  return this->motor_vector.size();
}
void Motor_Group::move(short speed)
{
  for(int i = 0;i<motor_vector.size();i++)
  {
    this->motor_vector[i].move(speed);//<- this move function is a function from the api in the 'main.h' , not the Motor_Group.move() one
    pros::lcd::print(i+1,"moved");
  }
  this->speed = speed;
}
float Motor_Group::position()
{
  float total = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i<size();i++)
  {
    total += this->motor_vector[i].get_position();
  }
  return total / this->size();
}
void Motor_Group::tare()
{
  for(int i = 0;i<this->size();i++)
  {
    this->motor_vector[i].tare_position();
  }
}

/*...*/
```

Comment: If a file name matters, it’s because your program is buggy (or at least depends on certain choices of unspecified behavior).  Here, how is `initialize` even being called?  (Ideally you would answer this by trimming irrelevant code and completing your example.)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57176331/how-to-implement-class-objects-in-header-file-c Order of initialization of static objects in different modules is unspecified, and that it alphabetical in this particular case is just "implementation detail" not some standard.